# Dynamics CRM - C# Plug-in for specific view

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've written a plugin in C# that runs when a specific view "My activities" for example is called. How can I specify my plugin ONLY to run when this view is called and not when "Closed activities", "All activities", etc. are?

And will the plugin I'm writing still work when Dynamics will be updated or in 1 year or 2?

Comment: That can't be done. What does the plugin do ? I'm curious (and positive this is a case of XY)

Comment: I'd like to display in a column the type of the regardingobject of my activities (eg. Is it an activity on a contact or on a society?). Io order to do that I added a field in society called "regarding_object_type". I use this field to create a column in my view and then with my plugin I'd like to fill that column in.

Comment: That should be a plugin on Update of the regardingobjectid attribute which fills the field. Dynamic fields built like that makes the CRM slow enough to be unuseable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a plugin it is not possible to determine which view the user exactly selected. You can however get access to the query the view is based upon.

Register your plugin for the synchronous post `RetrieveMultiple` message of the appropriate entity. The Inputparameters collection of the `IPluginExecutionContext` object will contain a property named "Query" holding the Original `QueryExpression`. You can examine this query (e.g. the columns that are selected) and tweak the entities returned by the query in the Outputparameters collection.

Years ago I successfully used this approach to provide realtime translations of data on a multi-language system.

Answer (score 1):

Just piggybacking off Henk's answer, you don't want to limit your plugin to run only when a specific view is requested anyway. If this column is always "empty" in the database, you really just want to inspect the ColumnSet of the submitted QueryExpression & do your manipulation *any* time the "calculated" column is requested. 
Once you get the ColumnSet from the query:

```
Query q = context.InputParameters.TryGetValue("Query") as QueryExpression; // could also be QueryByAttribute or FetchExpression,
if (q != null)
{
   ColumnSet cols = q.ColumnSet;
   if (cols.AllColumns == true || cols.Columns.Contains("regarding_object_type"))
   {    
       executionContext.OutputParameters["BusinessEntityCollection"] = GetResultValuesInWhateverWayYouAreGoingTo(); 
   }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.queryexpression.columnset.aspx